# How to add dtd validation to `xml.etree.cElementTree.iterparse`

Tags: python, xml, lxml, dtd

I know, that this way of dtd validation before parsing a xml file works:

```
    from lxml import etree
    context = etree.iterparse(PATH_TO_XML, dtd_validation=True, events=("start", "end"))
```

But how do I get this to work for the `xml.etree.cElementTree.iterparse`?

```
    from xml.etree.cElementTree import iterparse
    context = iterparse(PATH_TO_XML, ???, events=("start", "end"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cElementTree is not part of lxml.
According to the [cElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-dtd.htm) website, DTD Validation is not available to cElementTree.

Comment: According to this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270460/dtd-validation-with-python) DTD Validation is nto available to any builtin libraries. So you are stuck with lxml.