# how do i validate xml against dtd using python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file "sample.xml" as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8" ?>
< !DOCTYPE nodedescription SYSTEM "sample.dtd" >
<node_description>
    <target id="windows 32bit">
        <graphics>nvidia_970</graphics>
        <power_plug_type>energenie_eu</power_plug_type>
        <test>unit test</test>
   </target>
   <target id="windows 64bit">
       <graphics>nvidia_870</graphics>
       <power_plug_type>energenie_eu</power_plug_type>
       <test>performance test</test>
   </target>
</node_description>
```

and respective dtd as "sample.dtd":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT node_description (target)*>
<!ATTLIST target id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT target (graphics, power_plug_type, test)>
<!ELEMENT graphics (#PCDATA)*>
<!ELEMENT power_plug_type (#PCDATA)*>
<!ELEMENT test (#PCDATA)*>
```

I want "sample.xml" to get validated against "sample.dtd" by making use of python script. How will i achieve this? kindly help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DTD Validation With Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270460/dtd-validation-with-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I validate xml against a DTD file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798/how-do-i-validate-xml-against-a-dtd-file-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

The [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) lib is well suited for this:

With `sample.txt` and `sample.dtd` in the current working directory, you can simply run:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True)
tree = etree.parse("sample.xml", parser)
```

Results in:

```
XMLSyntaxError: root and DTD name do not match 'node_description' and 'nodedescription', line 3, column 18
```

See [here](http://lxml.de/validation.html) for more detail.  Also, [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392180/using-python-and-lxml-to-validate-xml-against-an-external-dtd)

Comment: I have got lxml package on my system but when i am running my script its not able to find module lxml. How to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe it's installed for a different python? try `pip install lxml`?